# Cant run simple JSF project in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, intellij-idea

I cant run a simple JSF project in IDEA. Where am I wrong? At first I created project with maven and it didn't work.
Next I tried to create a project via the standard menu:

[image]

And I got:

[image]

When I try to run it I get a `HTTP 404` tomcat error, tomcat app context is `/`.

Why doesn't it work?
I tried to accomplish the same goal in NetBeans, and it worked.

Comment: It is not needed. If you have "Index" page in your project and you don't specify other welcome-page in web.xml manually. Then the "index" - page you have, will shown by default as welcome-apge.

Answer (score 1):

Idea was making project not properly. In my case  IntelliJ Idea didn't include desired libraries. So i need to add it manually, like on the picture below

Or you can fix it by pressing button "*Fix..*" and chose *"add Mojarra-2.2.1 to the artifact"*

[image]

I hope it will help somebody!

Comment: Even with maven project i had a problem. I tried all. Before I started manage libraries manually.
http://i.imgsafe.org/da9544e.jpg